# Can some one tell me whats wrong with my JPQL query throwing me The basic mapping 's.surname' cannot be used in conjunction with the = operator error

Tags: java, jquery, jpql

I am trying to compare a name that is typed into a text box and a name inside the table but I keep getting this error 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT s FROM Salesmen s WHERE s.name = Linus ORDER BY s.name ASC]. 
[31, 37] The basic mapping 's.name' cannot be used in conjunction with the = operator.

My query is

```
SELECT s FROM Salesmen s WHERE s.name = Linus ORDER BY s.name ASC
```

Comment: What is `Linus`? Do you mean `'Linus'` (with quotes)?

Comment: if name is of the type VARCHAR, which I assume it is, you need to put parentheses around Linus: 'Linus'

Comment: Linus is the name itself I build the query like this       StartQ+ " " + decidera + " " + V1 + " " + V2 + " " + OB + " "+ OBI and V2 would be Linus oh and it is a Varchar

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be `SELECT s FROM Salesmen s WHERE s.name = 'Linus' ORDER BY s.name ASC`. `Linus` must be quoted, since it is a `varchar`. Just add to your query building strategy something like this (assuming `V2` is `Linus`):

`... V1 + " '" + V2 + "' " + OB ...`